# Ember - Automatically redirect to firstObject

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-router

I'd like an Ember path `/clinic/1` to automatically redirect to show the first doctor: `/clinic/1/doctor/1`.

Each clinic has many doctors.

Unfortunately if I use this code:

```
var doctor = clinicController.get('content.doctors.firstObject');
router.transitionTo('clinic.doctor.index', doctor);
```

... it does not work, as `content.doctors.length` is still `0` when this code runs in `app_router.js`.

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of ember do you use ? I think this code is before the new routing. Anyway, could make a jsfiddle or jsbin showing the example ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

```
App.DoctorsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Doctor.find();
  },

  redirect: function() {
    var doctor = this.modelFor('doctors').get('firstObject');
    this.transitionToRoute('doctor', doctor);
  }
});
```

This will work because:

- If the model hook returns an object that hasn't loaded yet, the rest of the hooks won't run until the model is fully loaded.
- If the `redirect` hook transitions to another route, the rest of the hooks won't run.

Note that as of [2426cb9](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/2426cb93ef9844d96219f399577e32fd7b667597), you can leave off the implicit `.index` when transitioning.

Comment: Is this still suppose to work with ember 1.0.0rc2? I'm always getting `this.modelFor('doctors').get('length')` at 0.

Comment: I'm trying this approach but it doesn't seem to work on the initial load.  I believe this is because the data has not loaded yet.  However, If I navigate away and come back, then it will work since at that time, the data HAS loaded.  any advice @Yahuda?

Comment: Also have problem that data has not loaded, when try this.modelFor. However when try console.log(this.modelFor('categories').get('isLoaded')); 
Returns me true, but content.length 0.

Comment: Was banging my head on this for ages and could absolutely not get it to work. I had child views rendering in the wrong parent or issues with my model not loaded. NOW I get why: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2116 and especially https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1642 cover the problem. Sounds like the workaround I am going to try will not involve Ember Data, as Ember Data apparently always returns promises

Comment: @MattSchweers: I was banging my head as well for a couple days. Did you find any workaround?

Comment: @PauloScardine I wish I could say I had but after I posted that comment, I have not had a chance to revisit my code. I am watching the GitHub issues I mentioned and there has been no progress on those items, so the the only real answer on my end will be ripping out Ember Data and rewriting my view/routing logic, which has not happened yet. Will update if I get a working solution in place

Comment: Also, how can I make it redirect only when no doctor route is selected  (no id is passed in from url)?

Comment: So is this not working anymore? When I try this I get an error in my console saying `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined`. For some reason `this.modelFor('doctors')` is returning undefined. It seems like the redirect hook is getting called before the model has finished loading.

Answer (score 2):

Redirecting on the Route doesn't work for me in my ember-data based app as the data isn't loaded at the point of redirection, but this does work for me...

In the roles controller I transition to the role route for the firstObject loaded.

```
Application.RolesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

    selectFirstObject: function () {
        if (this.get('content').get('isLoaded')) {
            var role = this.get('firstObject');
            this.transitionToRoute('role', role);
        }
    }.observes('content.isLoaded')

});
```

HTH, gerry

Answer (score 1):

As an update, if you don't want to redirect because you have a nested route, you'll want to use conditional redirect based on the intended route.

`redirect` has two arguments passed to it, the model and the transition object.  The transition has the property `targetName` where you can conditionally redirect based on its value.

```
redirect: function(model, transition){
  if(transition.targetName ==='doctors.index'){
    this.transitionTo('doctor', model.get('firstObject'));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For EmberCLI users, you'd achieve the same by doing the following:

```
//app/routes/clinics/show.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function(model) {
    var firstDoctor = model.get('doctors.firstObject');
    this.transitionTo('doctor', firstDoctor);
  }
});
```