# Redirecting to first item in ArrayController

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to redirect to the first item in an ArrayController.  I have found a few other questions related to this, but none had answers that seemed to work (a lot of changes have been happening so this is understandable).

One particular answer from Yehuda [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14306796/1157494):

```
App.DoctorsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Doctor.find();
  },

  redirect: function() {
    var doctor = this.modelFor('doctors').get('firstObject');
    this.transitionTo('doctor', doctor);
  }
});
```

I 'think' I have recreated this scenario, but I must have done something wrong...

Any insight into what I am doing wrong is greatly appreciated.

Example JSBin [here](http://jsbin.com/uxifus/2/edit).

Comment: I have the exact same issue.  It doesn't seem to work for me either.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that your list of models is not yet loaded from the server. Depending on your needs i would recomend using a promis to let the rout wait abit until your model is loaded.

```
App.DoctorsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Doctor.find().then(function (list) {
       return list.get('firstObject');
    });
  },

  redirect: function() {
    var doctor = this.modelFor('doctors');
    this.transitionTo('doctor', doctor);
  }
});
```

ofcourse.. wel that would make the redirect abit silly, so if you just want to wait for the list to load you could try:

```
App.DoctorsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Doctor.find();
  },

  redirect: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.modelFor('doctors').then(function (list) {
           return list.get('firstObject');
       }).then(function (doctor){
           if(!doctor)
              self.transitionTo('doctor', doctor);
       });
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried following this example, but the list I get have length 0 so the firstObject is undefined. Any work around? Thanks in advance!

Comment: well i gues your list is empty then. i supose you could always redirect to another route.. I'll put in below there. (just an idear.. let me know if it does not work)

Comment: I'm pretty sure I get results from the server, but the "return list.get('firstObject') line is still triggered before the list is available.