# EmberJS transitionTo firstObject for async hasMany

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ember.js, ember-data

I want to redirect users to the route for the firstObject of a collection when they arrive at the containing object.

A container `hasMany` items, currently in the `ContainerRoute.afterModel` I am doing:

```
this.transitionTo('container.item.index', model, model.get('items').get('firstObject'));
```

Which is fine when the items are not async.

The problem is the firstObject isn't a promise so the [route/transition doesn't pause](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/asynchronous-routing/).

Here is the `model` hook:

```
return this.get('store').find('container', params.containerId);
```

What's the cleanest approach?  The options I see are:

- change the model hook to populate the
- build and pass a promise as the parameter to transitionTo
- transitionTo the ID of the object instead of the object (writing a solution for this now)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirecting to first item in ArrayController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15401013/redirecting-to-first-item-in-arraycontroller)

Answer (score 0):

transitionTo can take an object (actual or promise), or an ID.

I opted to just send the ID in the `ContainerRoute`:

```
this.transitionTo('container.item.index', model, model.get('firstItemId'));
```

You can get the ID without inflating the object by accessing:

```
this.get('data.submissions.firstObject.id');
```

Which was borrowed from a [github issue about avoiding loadMany](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/586#issuecomment-11938331)

Answer (score 0):

The hasMany property is a promise like object, so you can use the `then` method, to know when it't is resolved:

```
model.get('items').then(function(items) {
  this.transitionTo('container.item.index', model, items.get('firstObject'));
});
```

Comment: Does that change the timing of the transition?  I was assuming that would result in a (potentially) delayed transition if the async call took some time.  I wouldn't want the user to get to the current route and then be transitioned away - might that happen?

Comment: If the `items` relation isn't loaded, a ajax request will be sent to the server. So that problem might happen.