# Redirect to first object in Ember array

Tags: javascript, redirect, ember.js

I got a partial solution from [Ember - Automatically redirect to firstObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14305255/ember-automatically-redirect-to-firstobject) but it's not working as expected:

My router:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('races', { path: '/'}, function() {
        this.resource('race', { path: '/:race_id'}, function() {
            this.route('edit');
            this.route('delete');
            this.route('splits');
        });
        this.route('create');
        this.route('info');
    });
});
```

Basically, I have a list of races and reach race has a time/pace view (the `race` resource). What I want is to never land on the `races` resource, so if I'm viewing a `race` and I delete it, I get redirected to the first `race`.

Using the solution from [Ember - Automatically redirect to firstObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14305255/ember-automatically-redirect-to-firstobject), EVERYTHING seems to redirect to the first `race` at which point all of my links and actions break and I "can't leave" the first `race` route.

Here's how I implemented the solution from the other post:

```
App.RacesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('race');
    },
    redirect: function(model) {
        var firstRace = this.modelFor('races').get('firstObject');
        this.transitionTo('race', firstRace);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`redirect` has two arguments passed to it, the model and the transition object.  The transition has the property `targetName` where you can conditionally redirect based on its value.

```
redirect: function(model, transition){
  if(transition.targetName =='races.index'){
    this.transitionTo('race', model.get('firstObject'));
  }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Works like a charm. Thanks for the concise explanation!